# Setting System Clock in licensing

Tags: c#, licensing, system-clock

I have developed a c# application that I wish to sell.You'll must be knowing that many people just reverse their system clock and keep using the software.How to prevent that
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most safe way would be to require access to the net to validate the time.
But access to the net is a strict requirement, especially for some scenarios of usage. 
In alternative you could try to keep an encrypted file in which you store the last time your application was launched. If the system clock on the next launch of your application is earlier than your stored last launch something must be fishy.

Comment: Thanks @Saverio.So I should use server for checking the time ?.Actually I am new to licensing and I want to build a good licensing software.Presently I am learning the basic concepts.Would you please guide me from where to start and what should I learn first?

Comment: Well I also had to handle such things, but I didn't really follow any guide. I started from my own experiences. I think that all of us in the past tried to force a licensing restriction. What gave us troubles? What did you do to circumvent those restrictions? Consider the scenario of usage of your software. Can I assume all my users always have access to the net? How should I handle the fact the user changes pc / formats it? If you're doing licensing through a serial, should you use hardware components ID to generate a key?

Comment: Thanks @Saverio.I will consider the above points.Anything else that I should keep in mind?